# Error in CA (data): The following variables are not quantitative:

Tags: r, data-analysis, factominer

(please if you see that my question is not good don't dislike it because this cause me problem later)

I tried to use `CA ()`  function from `library (FactoMineR)`
on a data that I read from a csv file, but I got some issues.

this the code I wrote:

````
``` data <- read.csv2("C:/Users/ahlem/Desktop/S1_IA/413(AnalyseDeDonnees)/2-TP/TP3/Data1.csv")
````

data

library (FactoMineR)

CA (data)```

And this is the result I got:

````
The following variables are not quantitative:  Droit.Sc.Eco.Lettres.Sciences.Medicine.Pharmacie.Pluridisc.IUT  ```
````

Comment: We can't see a .csv file on your C: drive. Please provide a reproducible example.